# Makefile: Perform specific command when one file was updated after another one

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a makefile which calls some bash scripts and shell commands.
One of those scripts generates a code (say, generated.h) file according to another code file (say source.h) - and I want it to be called only if source.h was updated after generated.h was updated.
(In pseudo code:

```
if update_time(generated.h) < update_time(source.h)  
  call GenerateCodeFile.sh  
end if
```

)

How can I do it from within a makefile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
generated.h: source.h
    sh GenerateCodeFile.sh
```

Be aware that that's a literal `<TAB>` character at the start of the `sh` line.